# python nested list comprehension in nltk

Tags: python, list-comprehension

This is a question from NLTK book but I got stuck. Any one know how to write this as a nested list comprehension?

```
>>> words = ['attribution', 'confabulation', 'elocution',
...          'sequoia', 'tenacious', 'unidirectional']
>>> vsequences = set()
>>> for word in words:
...     vowels = []
...     for char in word:
...         if char in 'aeiou':
...             vowels.append(char)
...     vsequences.add(''.join(vowels))
>>> sorted(vsequences)
['aiuio', 'eaiou', 'eouio', 'euoia', 'oauaio', 'uiieioa']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
In [75]: ["".join([char for char in word if char in 'aeiou']) for word in words]
Out[75]: ['aiuio', 'oauaio', 'eouio', 'euoia', 'eaiou', 'uiieioa']
```

If you need as `set` and `sorted`

```
sorted(set(["".join([char for char in word if char in 'aeiou']) for word in words]))
```